# c# how to perform a screen clipping similar to OneNote Windows + S shortcut key

Tags: c#, screen, overlay, onenote

I'd like to implement a similar screen clipping functionality to that of [OneNote](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-onenote/archive/2010/09/14/my-favorite-back-to-school-features-in-onenote-2010.aspx). Basically it can draw a translucent overlay on top of the whole screen, and also freeze the screen so users can clip a portion of it.

I've done some research around and it seems that the easiest way is to create a translucent TopMost form with the size of the whole screen and then perform clipping on this form. This approach, however, is slow. I see some other suggestions about doing a Direct3D hook for drawing overlay, but this is probably too complicated and I'm not sure how stable it is with respect to different Direct3D version. Any ideas how OneNote does it?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of creating the transparent layer on top of the screen, just grab a screenshot of the whole screen and make it full screen.  So users are drawing on a static image not a translucent layer.  Since it is a screenshot already, it is already frozen.  I think this is how they do it anyway, I doubt an application can simply freeze a screen, they take a photo of it and cover your screen with it, so its as if its frozen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have tried this approach before but it still seems slow compared to OneNote. By "freezing screen" I didn't actually mean the screen is frozen. I'm guessing that OneNote somehow has access to the drawing buffer through Direct3D and inject a constant image buffer to the drawing surface (in this case, would be the screenshot). Maybe this would make it much faster, but I didn't want to go with Direct3D unless it's my last resort.